# divide and multiply columns of a 2d based on user input in C

Tags: arrays, c, 2d

I made a code that does add, multiply, subtract and divide the columns of a 2d array,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int, int, int, int, int);
int mult(int, int, int, int, int);
int diff(int, int, int, int, int);
int quot(int, int, int, int, int);

int sum(int arr[100][100], int pro, int clo, int c, int r)
{
    for (c = 0; c < pro; c++)
    {
        int Colsum = 0;
        for (r = 0; r < clo; r++)
        {
            Colsum += arr[r][c];
        }
        printf("The sum of column %d is: %d\n", c + 1, Colsum);
    }
}

int mult(int arr[100][100], int pro, int clo, int c, int r)
{
    for (c = 0; c < pro; c++)
    {
        int Colsum = 1;
        for (r = 0; r < clo; r++)
        {
            Colsum *= arr[r][c];
        }

        printf("The product of column %d is: %d\n", c + 1, Colsum);
    }
}

int diff(int arr[100][100], int pro, int clo, int c, int r)
{
    for (c = 0; c < pro; c++)
    {
        int Colsum = 0;
        for (r = 0; r < clo; r++)
        {

            Colsum -= arr[r][c];
        }
        printf("The difference of column %d is: %d\n", c + 1, Colsum);
    }
}

int quot(int arr[100][100], int pro, int clo, int c, int r)
{
    for (c = 0; c < pro; c++)
    {
        int Colsum = 0;
        for (r = 0; r < clo; r++)
        {
            Colsum /= arr[r][c]
        }

        printf("The quotient of column %d is: %d\n", c + 1, Colsum);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[100][100];
    int rows, col;
    int i, j;

    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("Enter number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &col);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            printf("Element [%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("The table matrix is:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            printf("     %d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    sum(arr, rows, col, i, j);
    mult(arr, rows, col, i, j);
    diff(arr, rows, col, i, j);
    quot(arr, rows, col, i, j);
}
```

but the division and subtraction is not working properly, I already fixed multiplication.

Example of 2d array with 2 rows and 2 columns

```
5      4    
2      1
```

when I subtract the first column the answer is -7 and when I divide it the answer is always 0.

What is wrong in my function for subtraction and division?

Comment: All your function prototypes have a wrong first parameter, `int` ==> `int[100][100]`.

Comment: Compile with all warnings enables and treat warnings as errors

Comment: Enter number of rows: 2
Enter number of columns: 2
Element [0][0]: 5
Element [0][1]: 4
Element [1][0]: 2
Element [1][1]: 1
The table matrix is:
     5       4
     2       1
The sum of column 1 is: 7
The sum of column 2 is: 5
The product of column 1 is: 10
The product of column 2 is: 4
The difference of column 1 is: -7
The difference of column 2 is: -5
The quotient of column 1 is: 0
The quotient of column 2 is: 0

--------------------------------
Process exited after 3.686 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .

Still getting the wrong answer

Comment: What are you *trying* to do? Be specific in answering. For example, what mathematical expression would you be computing if the user wanted the “quotient of column 7” for a 100x100 array?

Comment: If you are operating on columns, then you should incrementing the column index in the inner loop and the row index in the outer loop.

Comment: Also `when I multiply it the answer is always 0` How is this correct if none of your elements are `0`?

Comment: i already changed it to a 2x2 for 2 columns and 2 rows